# Wd-Android wait before next click on alert dialog

Tags: android, webdriver, click, appium, ui-automation

My Android app asks for three run-time permissions. To allow the permission during the testing, I am using Wd-Android in Node JS to perform the click.

```
    var wdAndroid = new WdAndroid(wd);
driver = wdAndroid.promiseChainRemote(appiumServer);
driver.elementById('com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button').click();
driver.elementById('com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button').waitForLinearLayout().click();
driver.elementById('com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button').waitForLinearLayout().click();
```

As the permission alert dialog appears the first click works fine but the, the rest two clicks are not working. My assumption is that it takes time for the dialog to switch its view and ask for the second and third permission.

Is there a way to have a callback or wait Until functionality to force wait the flow until the dialog changes the context for next permission.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try sending your app to background for 0 secs to get your app focus back again

Try this:

```
driver.elementById('com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button').click();
driver.runAppInBackground(0)
driver.elementById('com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button').click();
driver.runAppInBackground(0)
driver.elementById('com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button').click();
driver.runAppInBackground(0)
```

I had also a problem with dialogs... When I accept or cancel them, I must do this trick to be able to use my driver again and resume my test...
Hope it helps